# Derivation Expected value of l-step ahead forcasting term

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, time-series

I have some trouble solving the following problem:

Given is the causal AR(1) model $X$:

$X_t = qX_{t-1}+Y_t$

Where $Y_t$ is distibuted $IID(0,\sigma^2)$

Now I'm trying to figure out how to derive:

$E[(P_nX_{n+l}-X_{n+l})^2]$$=\frac{1 -q^{2l} }{1 -q^{2}}\sigma^2$

Extra information given:
$l\ge1$ and $P_nX_{n+l}$ is the $l$-step ahead forecast.

Looking at the final equation of the derivation, it looks like the following rule will be used:

if $|\beta|\lt1$ then the summation of '$\beta^i$' from $i=0$ to $i=n-1$ is equal to:

$\frac{1 -\beta^{n} }{1 -\beta}$

How to get to such an equation with a summation is not clear to  me. Maybe it's because I am not very familiar with $l$-step ahead forcasting. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking at is the MSE. It can be rewritten as:

$$
\begin{align}
E[(\hat{X}_{n+l}-X_{n+l})^2]&=V(X_{n+l})+[X_{n+l}-E(\hat{X}_{n+l})]^2\\
&=V(X_{n+l})
\end{align}
$$
where the last equality is true because $E(\hat{X}_{n+l})=X_{n+l}$. Furthermore, this notation is a bit sloppy because actually we are doing this conditional on all $X$ up to $X_n$. So what we really want to find is:

$$
V(X_{n+l}|X_n, X_{n-1}, \dots)
$$
where we for simplicity will let $\mathcal{I}_n=\{X_t : t\leq n, \, t\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

$$
\begin{align}
V(X_{n+l}|\mathcal{I}_n)&=V(qX_{n+l-1}+Y_{n+l}|\mathcal{I}_n)=V(Y_{n+l}|\mathcal{I}_n)+q^2V(X_{n+l-1}|\mathcal{I}_n)\\
&=\sigma^2+q^2V(qX_{n+l-2}+Y_{n+l-1}|\mathcal{I}_n)\\
&=\sigma^2+q^2\sigma^2+q^4V(qX_{n+l-3}+Y_{n+l-2}|\mathcal{I}_n)\\
&\vdots\\
&=\sigma^2+q^2\sigma^2+q^4\sigma^2+\cdots+q^{2(l-1)}V(qX_{n}+Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{I}_n)\\
&=\sigma^2+q^2\sigma^2+q^4\sigma^2+\cdots+q^{2(l-1)}V(Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{I}_n)\\
&=\sigma^2+q^2\sigma^2+q^4\sigma^2+\cdots+q^{2(l-1)}\sigma^2\\
&=\sigma^2\sum_{k=0}^{l-1}\left(q^2\right)^k\\
&=\sigma^2\frac{1-\left(q^2\right)^l}{1-q^2}\\
&=\sigma^2\frac{1-q^{2l}}{1-q^2}.
\end{align}
$$
Some remarks:

1. $V(qX_{n}+Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{I}_n)=V(Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{I}_n)$ since $X_n$ is a constant (it's in the information set).
2. The condition for the sum of the geometric series is that $|q|<1$, and not that $|\beta|>1$ as you say.